# Misleading tensor notation for Jacobian inverse?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation, tensors

In Schutz, Geometrical Methods of Mathematical Physics, 
is written a Jacobian coordinate transform $\Lambda$, 
$$
 \Lambda^i_j = \frac{\partial x^i}{\partial y^j}
$$
The inverse matrix is written 
$$
   \Lambda^k_j = \frac{\partial y^k}{\partial x^j}
$$
Schutz then says (the fact that it is an inverse) 
"is easily proved using the chain rule for partial derivatives":
$$
  \frac{\partial x^i}{\partial y^j} \frac{\partial y^j}{\partial x^k} = \frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^k} = \delta^i_k
$$
Question 1: is it correct to regard this as a tensor contraction over "$\partial y^j$" ?

Next, Koks, Explorations in Mathematical Physics, has a similar example, but written
out in matrix notation:
$$
  \left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
  \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}  &\quad  \frac{\partial r}{\partial y}  \\
  \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}  &\quad  \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial y}  \\
  \end{array}
  \right]
  \cdot
  \left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
  \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}  &\quad  \frac{\partial x}{\partial\theta}  \\
  \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}  &\quad  \frac{\partial y}{\partial\theta}  \\
  \end{array}
  \right]
= \left[\begin{array}{cc}
       1 &\quad 0 \\
       0 &\quad 1
  \end{array}\right]
$$

Rewrite this using $\partial x^1 \equiv \partial r$, $\partial x^2 \equiv \partial\theta$, 
$\partial y^1 \equiv \partial x$, $\partial y^2 \equiv \partial y$
so that it matches the Shutz notation:
$$
  \left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
  \frac{\partial x^1}{\partial y^1}  &\quad  \frac{\partial x^1}{\partial y^2}  \\
  \frac{\partial x^2}{\partial y^1}  &\quad  \frac{\partial x^2}{\partial y^2}  \\
  \end{array}
  \right]
  \cdot
  \left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
  \frac{\partial y^1}{\partial x^1}  &\quad  \frac{\partial y^1}{\partial x^2}  \\
  \frac{\partial y^2}{\partial x^1}  &\quad  \frac{\partial y^2}{\partial x^2}  \\
  \end{array}
  \right]
= \left[\begin{array}{cc}
       1 &\quad 0 \\
       0 &\quad 1
  \end{array}\right]
$$
Now look at an individual element of the matrix product. 
Applying the chain rule from Schutz,
$$
  \frac{\partial x^i}{\partial y^j} \frac{\partial y^j}{\partial x^k} = \frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^k} = \delta^i_k
$$
however if we write this out explicitly for the 1,1 element:
$$
  \frac{\partial x^1}{\partial y^1}\frac{\partial y^1}{\partial x^1} + \frac{\partial x^1}{\partial y^2}\frac{\partial y^2}{\partial x^1} = 2 \frac{\partial x^1}{\partial x^1} = 2
$$
Question 2: this is incorrect...

Comment: You can't "cancel" $\partial y^1$ in $\frac{\partial x^1}{\partial y^1}\frac{\partial y^1}{\partial x^1}$, that's not how the chain rule works in several variables.

Comment: $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ is not a quotient @beginner

Comment: Is this not a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778149/jacobian-times-its-inverse-should-be-identity ? I think that this answer is more satisfying, since it basically tells you that your method is not wrong but there is just an error in the application.

Answer (score 2):

There is an implicit sum over all values of $j$ in Schutz's notation; his statement is not that
$$\frac{\partial x^1}{\partial y^1} \frac{\partial y^1}{\partial x^1} = 1$$
but rather that
$$\frac{\partial x^1}{\partial y^1} \frac{\partial y^1}{\partial x^1} +\frac{\partial x^1}{\partial y^2} \frac{\partial y^2}{\partial x^1}= 1$$
i.e.,
$$\sum_j \frac{\partial x^1}{\partial y^j} \frac{\partial y^j}{\partial x^1} = 1$$
and his statement that
$$\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial y^j} \frac{\partial y^j}{\partial x^k} = \delta^i_k$$
has an implicit summation:
$$\sum_j \frac{\partial x^i}{\partial y^j} \frac{\partial y^j}{\partial x^k} = \delta^i_k$$